# can´t load resource javascript with relative path ${pageContext.request.contextPath}

Tags: javascript, jsp, relative-path

im trying to load a script from a folder i defined in the classpath into a jsp page like this

```
<script src="${pageContext.request.contextPath}/src/main/webapp/WEB-INF/asset/javascript/formToJson.js"></script>
```

but i got a 404 error and the url seems good based on the local location of the folder inside the project.

In the classpath i added the asset folder which contain a package called javascript.

this is the first time that i work with relative paths is probably im missing something in my configuration

Any advice will be appreciated

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try changing to:

```
<script src="${pageContext.request.contextPath}/WEB-INF/asset/javascript/formToJson.js"></script>
```

Generally, resources under `/src/main/webapp/` is deployed in Web application's context path.